# How to write an R code for searching keywords?

Tags: r, select, title, article, keyword-search

My goal is to investigate: whether an article title or it's abstract contain keywords, and to select or mark theese articles somehow (creating a new category, like contain/not comtain any of a keyword list). I collected theese articles in an excel file, i have its titles, abstract there. What are the steps to consider in this situation? I have very little experience btw, just started to learn R, and I came from psychology field.

I haven't started yet, just wondering how it could be solved

Comment: You can use `grep` to search for keywords, possibly wrapped in a `sapply` or similar. More details can be given if a sample of the data is posted, ideally with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this question is too broad for this site. I recommend finding a tutorial on searching through data using R first, try to write some code, and then coming here to ask about any _specific_ questions you have. Asking for help with learning a new programming language (or how to program in general) is out of scope on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample data and code to get you started (with comments to guide you through the code):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define sample data
df <- tibble(
  title = c("Programming in R", "How to post on StackOverflow", "A pasta recipe"),
  abstract = c("This is an article about reproducible resesarch.", "Have a question on coding? Learn how to ask anything.", "Ingredients: 2 eggs, a little flour.")
)

# define keyword
keywords <- "programming|coding"

# create indicator column that is TRUE if either title or abstract contain any keyword
df |>
  mutate(about_programming = str_detect(title, regex(keywords, ignore_case = TRUE)) |
           str_detect(abstract, regex(keywords, ignore_case = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   title                        abstract                        about_programming
#>   <chr>                        <chr>                           <lgl>            
#> 1 Programming in R             This is an article about repro… TRUE             
#> 2 How to post on StackOverflow Have a question on coding? Lea… TRUE             
#> 3 A pasta recipe               Ingredients: 2 eggs, a little … FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>